# Is there an access log library for netty?

Tags: netty

Is there a library that create access log for Netty? It would be nice if it is compatible with apache access log and configurable like apache. For example an access log configuration in apache:

```
"%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth checking out this implementation that someone has done:
https://gist.github.com/jbowes/1065230

Answer (score 0):

Nope not that I'm aware of. But it should be not to hard to write one by using your favorit logging library.